# For loop not working in PHP script

Tags: php

I have written a PHP script to pull data from a SQL database to display on a webpage. Everything seems fine but when I run the script it throws the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in db_data.php on line 21

Line 21 is my FOR loop, I have checked the syntax of the loop and it seems to be correct so I can't understand why it is failing.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * igi");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Ref</th>
<th>Nameame</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Issue</th>
<th>Urgency</th>
</tr>";

for($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['REF'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LOCATION'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ISSUE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['URGENCY'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: its not for loop its while loop `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){`

Comment: Use the appropriate `while()` loop, not a `for()` loop.... learn why both exist

Comment: because **that** is not how a **[for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)** loop works. try a **[while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)** instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change for to while

```
<?php
//                   Missing FROM here vv
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM igi");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Ref</th>
<th>Nameame</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Issue</th>
<th>Urgency</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['REF'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['LOCATION'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['ISSUE'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['URGENCY'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I changed the for to a while and it is now throwing this error... mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in db_data.php on line 21

Comment: @SiobhanSykes and **that** is because your query is wrong, fails, and returns false instead of a result set. try adding a `FROM`

Comment: SELECT * __FROM__ igi

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony Thompson and RJParick says, you have to change `for` to `while`. The error you're encountering is due tu `for` that need 3 params like this :

```
for($i; $i<10; $i++) {//Note the ; used to separate params.
    //do something
}
```

So your loop would begin like this :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Another detail, your SQL isn't correct use `SELECT * FROM igi` instead.